# How to fix subdivision surface glitches

Tags: subdivision-surface

So, I'm trying to make a shoe, but I've noticed there are a lot of glitches including: pinching, areas that are not properly filled and random sharp edges as well as edges that are overly curved and not smooth.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've checked the un-subbed topology and there's no random vertexes and it's relatively even and clean

Comment: it can be: inverted normals (try a Shift N), overlapping vertices (try a M to Merge by Distance), or inner faces... If it still doesn't fix your problem please share your file

Comment: That worked! Thanks!